# using isinstance () gives me True , using type() gives me False in Python

Tags: python

While i was trying to solve a problem in some course i am taking , i ended facing something i don't know how to overcome.

I need to code a method in a Class it represents a matrix , this method for vector_matrix multiplication , now the instructor provided us a code represents the Class and it contains the class definition , our duty is to complete some procedures (methods) .

the code i was working in its name is vector_matrix_mul(v, M) where v is a vector , M is a matrix this method will be in the Class Mat that we are designing, now i wrote a code and it runs fine on my computer , but the problem is that.

the Class Mat has the following method .

```
def __rmul__(self, other):
    if Vec == type(other):
        return vector_matrix_mul(other, self)
    else:  # Assume scalar
        return scalar_mul(self, other)
```

here Vec is a class for vectors , now in order for my method which is vector_matrix_mul(other, self) to be executed the condition before it has to be True , but i am getting it False so the program runs to the else: part and execute other procedure .

i tried to substitute the condition contains type() so the code above becomes as follows:

```
def __rmul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Vec):
        return vector_matrix_mul(other, self)
    else:  # Assume scalar
        return scalar_mul(self, other)
```

and the code was working , so now i don't know how to avoid this problem , when testing my program the if Vec == type(other): is giving False for all the instances of the Class Vec , is there a way to get the result of if Vec == type(other): is similar to the result of the condition if isinstance(other, Vec):   ??

or any suggestion to make the condition if Vec == type(other): giving True.

one note : i am using Python 3.2.3 while the grader is using Python 3.3.2

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isinstance()` tests for the type *or subclasses* of that type.

Don't ever use `== type(..)`; you would use `issubclass()` instead:

```
issubclass(type(other), Vec)
```

but `isinstance()` is much better as it avoids having to look up the type in the first place.

Last but not least, types are singletons, testing for `is` identity would be marginally better:

```
Vec is type(other)
```

but not much better.

Note that for *old style classes* (anything not inheriting from `object`) `type()` will not return the class, but `<type 'instance'>` instead; you'd have to use `other.__class__` instead. `isinstance()` correctly handles that situation:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<type 'instance'>
>>> f.__class__
<class __main__.Foo at 0x1006cb2c0>
>>> type(f) is Foo
False
>>> f.__class__ is Foo
True
>>> isinstance(f, Foo)
True
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn , i appreciate your explanation , but the point is that type(..) is included in the automatic grader , so i can't change it , and my code runs correct if type(..) was substituted by isinstance(..., ...) .so i don't know what i have to do in order to make those instances of the class Vec satisfying the following condition if Vec == type(other): so it can result True then my method will be graded and executed.

Comment: Are you telling me your course is *forcing* you to use bad python practices? How does it check for the presence of `type()`?

Comment: And if `type(other)` is not `Vec` but `isinstance` is returning `True` then `other` must be an instance of a subclass, not of `Vec` itself.

Comment: I didn't mean that the course is using good or bad practices, actually i don't feel brave enough to evaluate , i am just a beginner, but we are provided with a code contains some definitions of a class its name is Mat and we have to complete some other methods included the one i mentioned above, the code of the class Mat includes the condition contains type() and that makes me not able to test my piece of code i have written because the grader evaluate type() and result to False then it goes to the else option to run some other method , so i am here to hear your opinions, thank you.

Comment: I think that you mentioned very important point here , yes other is an instance when i check using type i get the following <type 'instance'> so it is not an instance of Vec but it is instance of subclass , i think that i have to check why it is not an instance of Vec.

Comment: @mazlor: ah, that is an important clue. Updated the answer. You cannot **possibly** use `type()` in that case. Stick to `isinstance()`.